# How do I shutdown the system after a particular process exits

Tags: command-line, process, shutdown, exit

I am downloading some software; I can see the `pid` of the download process with `top`.  Let's say it's `1001`.

How can I make it so that my computer shuts down after process `1001` exits?

Answer (score 3):

This one-liner loop checks ps output for the process ID 1001, and sleeps for 2 seconds then checks again until it doesn't find it (the process has exited), at which point the loop ends and it moves on to the next command which is a shutdown.

`while [[ $(ps 1001 &> /dev/null)$? -eq 0 ]]; do sleep 2 ;done && shutdown -h now`

If you want to make sure that process 1001 is the process you think it is, you can add grep to test, for instance if the process should be iTunes, you could do:

`while [[ $(ps 1001 |grep -q "iTunes" &> /dev/null)$? -eq 0 ]]; do sleep 2 ;done && shutdown -h now`

Comment: @Ramesh I had this as a one liner, if you are going to edit it to be multiline then the semi-colons no longer make sense.  I felt the benefit to having it as a one-liner was that he could run it in the Terminal easily, without having to worry about potential copy and paste carriage return/new line issues.

Comment: No problem. You can edit it as you want. But give some description of what the command does :)

Answer (score 2):

Here you go. tested and working.

```
while [ 1 ] ; do 
   ps 1001 > /dev/null || { shutdown -h now ; break ; }
   sleep 1
done
```

Comment: That may need to run as root, depending on config. Often non-root isn't allowed to run `shutdown -h` (and `-r`, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Run the following commands:

```
while kill -0 1001 &> /dev/null; 
do
   sleep .1
done;
poweroff
```

Using `kill -0` sends no actual signal, but will report true while a given process is running. The redirect `&>` goes to `/dev/null` (bit-bucket) so any errors or success messages are not included in the output of your program. This will sleep a tenth of a second and check the process until it is no longer running, then will execute a `poweroff`.

Comment: Using kill -0 sends no actual signal, but will report true while a given process is running. The redirect &> goes to /dev/null (bit-bucket) so any errors or success messages are not included in the output of your program. This will sleep a tenth of a second and check the process until it is no longer running, then willexecute a poweroff.